# How do I use a java splash screen when jar launched from the command line?

Tags: java

I have set up a splash screen to be used by my application in the manifest.  If I create my jar using eclipse, the splash screen is displayed when I double click the jar.  However, when I try to launch my application from the command line using java -classpath blah.jar, I get no splashscreen.  I have also tried specifying java -splash:Resources/blah.png [...], but this doesn't work either (Resources/blah.png is my path within my jar).

I need to have it work through the command line for two reasons.  First, some of the client machines may not have their system configured correctly to run the jar directly by double clicking. Second, through the command line I want to set my heap size and perm space size since in some cases it may be needed (it would be great to be able to do this through my manifest).

Lastly, I'd rather not have an images directory floating around separate to my jar.

In short, how do I use a java splash screen specified in the manifest when the jar is launched from the command line?  Second, is there a good way to set my heap and permspace sizes without launching through the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch the app with the `-jar` option instead of the `-cp` option. This tells java to load the classpath, the main class and other options like the splash screen from the jar's manifest:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

That's the command that the system uses when double-clicking on a jar (except it uses `javaw` and not `java`).

If you want to have a double-clickable file which sets the heap and permgen size, then create a `.bat`/`.sh` file, or use a tool like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Excellent.  That worked for launching through the command line and displaying the splash.  However, when I specify 
java -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -jar my.jar
I get errors about not being able to reserve enough space.  It works fine when I use -cp with no splash.  What do you think?
Actually, it worked to reduce the allocation...apparently you have to allocate less when the splash screen.  Any ideas about setting the heap and permspace sizes through the jar only?

Comment: @Skcussm how much RAM do you have available on your machine?

Comment: 4GB on Windows XP.  I guess I was right at the edge of the available memory, and adding the splash caused the jvm to pre-allocate some additional memory pushing my request over the limit.  Seem plausible?